# Mysql query with two AND

Tags: mysql

I'm having some troubles with a query that seems easy but I'm not able to find a solution.

I have a table like this one

```
id     pro_code     pro_category
1         5            14
2         6            13
3         7            13
4         6            18
5         7            14
6         5            13
7         8            14
8         9            13
```

I need to take with a single query only distinct pro_code where pro_category is equal to 13 and 14 (both values).

This is the query

```
SELECT pro_code FROM mytable WHERE pro_category=13 and pro_category=14 GROUP BY pro_code
```

The result I receive is zero records.
What I expect as result is  5 and 7 because 5 and 7 has both pro_category values 13 and 14. Other records have one of them and not both.

Where is the mistake?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IN clause and a HAVING clause to guarantee that the rows returned have both values.

```
SELECT pro_code 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE pro_category IN (13, 14) 
    GROUP BY pro_code
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pro_category) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "or" instead of "and". Logical "and" here gives you empty set

Comment: in this way I will have 5,6,7,8,9 as result. I need only 5 and 7

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are phrasing the question wrong: You don't want *distinct pro_code where pro_category is equal to 13 and 14*, as those cannot exist, but you want *distinct pro_code which have both a pro_category of 13 and of 14*.

This ofcourse completely changes your query logic - you now need to select twice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first.pro_code
FROM tablename AS first
INNER JOIN tablename AS second ON first.pro_code=second.pro_code
WHERE first.pro_category=13
AND second.pro_category=14
;
```